# Duplicate TODO keywords defined in init.el

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have the following TODO keywords defined in init.el

```
  (org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO(t)"
                                 "STARTED(s)"
                                 "WAITING(w)"
                                 "NEXT(n)" "|"
                                 "POSTPONED(p)"
                                 "SOMEDAY(m)"
                                 "DONE(d)"
                                 "CANCELLED(c)")
                       (sequence "TOLEARN(l)"
                                 "TOREVIEW(r)" "|"
                                 "DONE(d)"
                                 "CANCELLED(c)")))
```

Since I have `DONE(d)` and `CANCELLED(C)` in both sequences I see them twice when I press `C-c C-t` to get a menu of all the keywords.

Is is okay to have it like that or should I create a separate sequence for DONE and CANCELLED, something like this:

```
  (org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO(t)"
                                 "STARTED(s)"
                                 "WAITING(w)"
                                 "NEXT(n)" "|"
                                 "POSTPONED(p)"
                                 "SOMEDAY(m)")
                       (sequence "TOLEARN(l)"
                                 "TOREVIEW(r)" "|")
                       (sequence "|" "DONE(d)"
                                 "CANCELLED(c)")))
```

This way I think I avoid duplication.
Or do the DONE and CANCELLED need to be part of their sequence?

Comment: I have not tried it but my guess would be that the second would not work. However, feel free to try it and answer your own question.

Comment: The structure of the keywords only seems to be important if you use the arrow keys to change the todo state, with `C-c C-t` you can jump from anywhere to anywhere.